# How to apply a dark blue filter on an slider image

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters, css-filters

I'm trying for already a couple of hours to make a dark blue filter!
So, not only a "greyscale" use or brightness filters.
I've heard about SVG and tried to understand how to use it in that case, but I don't even know if SVG would work in my case, tried all these webkit filters, and filters properties, and I really can't get that dark blue filter

And on google I couldn't find how to make a dark blue filter , or other custom filter

I can only by editing the image myself, but I really need to make it with CSS, JS or something.

I show you the result wanted :

Image without filter
[image: Image without filter]

Image with filter
[image: Image with filter]

If anyone could help me by giving some ideas or some code to help it would be very nice

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/qJCDk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in css, one approach is to use a `pseudoelement` on the image container.

Give the `pseudoelement` the background colour you want and set an `opacity`. You can use `rgba` here instead if you like.

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  background: darkblue;
  opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/45yOV.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Wrapper

```
<style>
    #Wrapper{
        background:url(http://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg);
        width:1300px;
        height:1300px;
    }

    #Content{
        background-color:rgba(74, 136, 209,0.7);
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
</style>
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Content">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Come to the world of `<canvas>` and this task will be a breeze. Eg. [FarbicJS](http://fabricjs.com/) will give you a lot of filters, but make sure to custom build your lib so it doesn't get too big. Or choose from many others [here on github](https://github.com/search?p=2&q=canvas%20filter&ref=opensearch&type=Repositories).

I think this one looks good too: https://www.viget.com/articles/instagram-style-filters-in-html5-canvas

Answer (score -1):

Use a combination of CSS `filter` properies...`contrast` and `brightness` seem to work quite well.

```css
div {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  filter: contrast(45%) brightness(95%)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/45yOV.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```